# Изменение размера элемента в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Как можно изменить размер объекта (например кнопки) в JavaFX?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Как вы пробовали изменять размер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы для изменения размера (унаследованы от [javafx.scene.layout.Region](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setMaxHeight-double-)):

```
button.setMinWidth(double value)
button.setMaxWidth(double value)
button.setPrefWidth(double value)

button.setMinHeight(double value)
button.setMaxHeight(double value)
button.setPrefHeight(double value)

button.setMinSize(double minWidth, double minHeight)
button.setMaxSize(double maxWidth, double maxHeight)
button.setPrefSize(double prefWidth, double prefHeight)
```

По сигнатурам методов (`setMin*`, `setMax*`) легко понять, что они делают. `setPrefWidth`, `setPrefHeight`, `setPrefSize` устанавливают *предпочтительные* размеры - если места достаточно для отображения кнопки с указанным размером - она будет такой, иначе размер будет изменен (с учетом min  и max размеров).